# Is $T$ a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have this question which I solved and would like to verify the answers:

For each $T$ define whether it is a linear transformation:

1. $T:\mathbb R_n[x]\rightarrow \mathbb R_n[x]$, where $T(p(x))=(x+1)p'(x)$ and $p'(x)$ is the derivative of $p(x)$
2. $T: \mathbb R ^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2,\ \ T(x,y)=(2x-y, 3|x|, y)$
3. $T:M^{\mathbb R}_{n\times n} \rightarrow M^{\mathbb R}_{n\times n},\ \ T(X)=X^2-X$

My solutions are:

1. $T(cp(x))=c(x+1)p'(x)=cT(p(x))\\T(p(x)+q(x))=(x+1)p'(x)+(x+1)q'(x)=T(p(x))+T(q(x))$

The transformation is linear.

2. $T(cx,cy)=(2cx-cy, 3|cx|, cy)=(c(2x-y), 3c|x|, cy)=c(2x-y, 3|x|, y)=cT(x,y)\\T(x+a, y+b)=(2(x+a)-(y+b), 3|x+a|, y+b)$

$3|x+a|\le 3|x|+3|a|$ - hence $T(x+a, y+b)\le T(x, y) + T(a, b)$

This transformation is not linear

3. $T(X)=X^2-X=X(X-1)\\T(cX)=cX(cX-1)\neq cT(X)$

Hence the transformation is not linear.

Could you please tell me whether it's right or maybe I'd made a mistake somewhere?

**Udate**

According to the comments below I've changed the solutions:

2. $T(cx,cy)=(2cx-cy, 3|cx|, cy)\\c<0\rightarrow c|x|\neq |cx|\rightarrow T(cx, cy) \neq cT(x,y)$

This does not fulfill the requirement of $T(cx)=cT(x), c\in \mathbb R $, thus the transformation is not linear.

3. $T(X)=X^2-X=X(X-1)\\T(cX)=cX(cX-1)\neq cT(X)\ for\ c\neq 0, 1$

This does not fulfill the requirement of $T(cx)=cT(x), c\in \mathbb R $, thus the transformation is not linear.

Comment: There is an error in 2. Note that $|cx| \neq c|x|$ if $c < 0$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Wonderful! Totally missed that one. Thanks!

Comment: For 2 and 3 it suffices to provide a counterexample. In fact, any time you are asked to show that a property doesn't hold, odds are good that the best approach will be furnishing a counterexample. The risk you run if you don't just give a counterexample is that you might assert something which is not true. For example, when $c = 1$, $T(cX) = cT(X)$, contrary to your proof.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Does it mean I have to explicitly define $c\in \mathbb R$ in this kind of solutions?

Comment: You can’t say that $T(x+a,y+b)\leq T(x,a)+T(y,b)$ because we don’t order triples $(u,v,w).$ Also, $\leq$ can include $=.$ What you need to prove something is *not* linear is specific values where the linearity fails. You are right, sometimes $|x+a|\neq |x|+|a|,$ and thus (2) is not linear. Do the Sam with (3).

Comment: To echo @ThomasAndrews comment, when you are trying to show linearity, you are trying to show that for all $x,y$ and all $a,b$, we have $T(ax + by) = aT(x) + bT(y)$. To disprove linearity, it suffices to find some $x,y$ and $a,b$ such that $T(ax + by) \neq aT(x) + bT(y)$. You get to pick them to make the proof as easy as possible for yourself. It comes down to the fact that "not for all" is logically equivalent to "there exists not." See [here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~aloveles/Math300Winter2011/m300Quantifiers.pdf).